# pandas criterias for groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am struggling with pandas grouping, something which is probably very simple to solve. 
e.g.

```
name  number
A    10
A    8

B    7
B    6
B    9
```

In this dataset, what is the easiest vectorization method, with which I can exclude ALL line items of category (column) "name" where the minimum value of "number" is below 8. 
In above all B would be deleted, as there is minimum one element which has a value lower than 8.

I believe it must be possible with `groupby`, `apply` or `filter`, but do not remember, how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
In [3281]: df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x['number'].min() >= 8)
Out[3281]:
  name  number
0    A      10
1    A       8
```

---

Details

```
In [3282]: df
Out[3282]:
  name  number
0    A      10
1    A       8
2    B       7
3    B       6
4    B       9
```

Comment: Many Thanks! I tried that before, but made a mistake somewhere... Now I copied your code and it works! Ultra-fast response!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `min` for mask and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter:

```
print (df.groupby('name')['number'].transform('min') >=8)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: number, dtype: bool

df = df[df.groupby('name')['number'].transform('min') >=8]
print (df)
  name  number
0    A      10
1    A       8
```

Comment: @GigiHofleitner dont forget to vote to show your gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `apply` too (for the sake of completeness).

```
mask = df.groupby('name')['number'].apply(lambda x : (x>=8).all())
# or Thanks @Zero mask = df.groupby('name')['number'].min() >= 8
df[df['name'].isin(mask[mask].index)]
```

Output:

```
  name  number
0    A      10
1    A       8
```

Comment: Why `apply` when you can `df.groupby('name')['number'].min() >= 8`?

Comment: No OP stated `apply` `transform` `filter` na so added an apply based solution :). Might show things done with heavy work. :):) Sir and wonderful solutions from you sometimes stays in comments TBH.